# How can i color change a <div> in a django template depending on a model field?

Tags: django, django-templates

i have a model in models.py containing a field which indicate its default color (green) and with a method its supposed to change to amber if the future date(another field) is equal to timezone.now(). However whenever i run the webapp, all objects display green even if the dates are the same. what can i change or

```
     {% for prestamo in prestamos %}
        <style>
        .activo{
            text-align: center;
            background-color: {{prestamo.color_id}};
            margin: 50px;
            padding: 20px;
            border-radius: 25px;
        }
        </style>
        <div class="activo">
        <ul style="list-style-type:none;">
            <li>{{prestamo.item}}</li>
            <li>numID: {{prestamo.num_serie}}</li>
            <li>Equipo: {{prestamo.nom_equipo}}</li>
            <li>Nombre: {{prestamo.empleado}}</li>
            <li>Departamento: {{prestamo.departamento}}</li>
            <li>{{prestamo.correo}}</li>
            <li>Engrega: {{prestamo.fecha}}</li>
            <li>Expira: {{prestamo.entrega}}</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

    def return_date_time():
        now = timezone.now()
        return now + timedelta(days=15)

class prestamo(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    num_serie = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    nom_equipo = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    empleado = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    correo = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    departamento = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    fecha = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True) 
    entrega = models.DateField(default=return_date_time) 
    color_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='#1DB03C', editable=False)
    
    def prestamoExpirado():
        if prestamo.entrega != timezone.now():
            prestamo.color_id ='#1DB03C'
        elif prestamo.entrega == timezone.now():
            prestamo.color_id = '#FFBF00'
        return prestamo.color_id
            
    def __str__(self):
        return self.item
```

Comment: You forgot the `self` in the method parameters and in the method itself, change `prestamo` with `self`.

Comment: like this?
def prestamoExpirado(self):
        if prestamo.entrega != timezone.now():
            prestamo.color_id ='#1DB03C'
        elif prestamo.entrega == timezone.now():
            prestamo.color_id = '#FFBF00'
        return self.color_id

Comment: Your halfway through. You need to change the `prestamo` inside the method too.

Comment: def prestamoExpirado(self):
       if self.entrega != timezone.now():
            self.color_id ='#1DB03C'
        elif self.entrega == timezone.now():
            self.color_id = '#FFBF00'
        return self.color_id

Comment: That should do it if there is no other errors in your code.

Comment: so now i can just call the prestamo.color_id field inside my css in home.html?

Comment: Yes. Please also keep in mind that the comments section is not a chat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of a field in a model, you can have a function that would return the proper class or style in your template.

**models.py**

```
def prestamo_color(self):
    if self.entrega != timezone.now():
       return 'activo--green'
    elif self.entrega == timezone.now():
       return 'activo--red'
```

**template**

```
<div class="activo {{prestamo.prestamo_color}}">
```

Comment: i also had to change timezone.now() for datetime.date.today(), Thanks a lot!